# How to install network certificates on android device without security settings?

Tags: android

I'd like to preface this by saying that I am completely new to using Android devices, so I've been relying solely on internet searches and help forums to solve this issue.

I need to install a network certificate onto an LEMX Smartwatch made by LEMFO. I have downloaded the certificate to the watch through USB, and according to every set of instructions I've been able to find the next step involves going into the Security Settings. Unfortunately for me, there are no such settings on the LEMX. Going into Settings only has the following tabs: `Sound`, `Display`, `App List Style`, `Connect` (which allows me to select certificates but has no option for downloading new ones), `Gesture`, `Power saving`, `Languages & Input`, `Date & time`, `Reset equipment`, `Uninstall Application`, `More` (which does not have the Security settings either), and About watch. As far as I can tell this is due to some strange choice by the manufacturer to remove the `Security` tab.

Is there another way for me to install a network certificate onto the watch?

Comment: You probably need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: You'll need to contact LEMFO.